# How to read Received fields in the mail header?

Tags: email

The following is an example of a email header (just the received part):

```
Delivered-To: aaaa@gmail.com
Received: by 10.79.29.73 with SMTP id d70csp1033542ivd;
        Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:13:50 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.28.85.137 with SMTP id j131mr14088045wmb.15.1460319230220;
        Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:13:50 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bbbb@sur5r.net>
Received: from libri.sur5r.net (libri.sur5r.net. [217.8.49.41])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l10si24947537wjx.231.2016.04.10.13.13.49
        for <aaaa@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:13:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bbbb@sur5r.net designates 217.8.49.41 as permitted sender) client-ip=217.8.49.41;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bbbb@sur5r.net designates 217.8.49.41 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bbbb@sur5r.net
Received: from samsa.sur5r.net (samsa.hd.sur5r.net [2001:470:1f15:53:21c:bfff:fec3:a0bb])
  (AUTH: PLAIN samsa, TLS: TLSv1/SSLv3,256bits,DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)
  by libri.sur5r.net with ESMTPSA; Sun, 10 Apr 2016 22:13:49 +0200
  id 000000000000000B.570AB3FD.00004739
Received: from samsa.sur5r.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by samsa.sur5r.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0B09910A113D;
    Sun, 10 Apr 2016 22:13:47 +0200 (CEST)
```

As you can see it contains a lot of information. I know this indicates a route from the sender to the receiver, but I don't really know how to read this header. Can anyone explain what actually happens to the message based on the info above? Why the first `Received:` is 127.0.0.1? Shouldn't it be some public IP address? How am I supposed to know whether the message is a spam or it was forged somehow?

Comment: Nothing about it is specific to UNIX -- it's about mail transport and (possible) forgery. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You may not rely on headers unless they are signed with DKIM (see http://www.dkim.org/). It is completely fine to have `Received:..from 127.0.0.1`: the `MSA` (Message Submission Agent) could be configured to send messages to locally running `MTA` (Message Transfer Agent). Thus, the `MTA` places legitimate header it received the message from localhost.

Comment: As for designating the message as legitimate one - accept only messages with `DKIM` signatures that passes the checks. The rest is a SPAM.

Comment: @Serge that's nonsense.  Plenty of legitimate mail servers don't run DKIM.  And plenty of spammers sign their spam with DKIM (or send through a service like gmail or yahoo etc that do).    Lack of DKIM is **not** a sign of spam, and a DKIM signature is **not** proof that a message isn't spam.   As for relying on Received: headers, they are trivially forged.   The only ones you can **really** trust are those added by your own server, view all other Received: headers with deep suspicion.

Comment: @cas, I did not say that DKIM is an ultimate proof. Anyway, relying only on headers will not solve the problem. Even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering gives false positives though this is a way to go. As for legitimate servers not using DKIM - it always up to you to decide what signs are important for you and what are not to mark a message as SPAM

Comment: You said "accept only messages with DKIM signatures that passes the checks. The rest is a SPAM".  That can't mean anything but "DKIM is an ultimate proof."

Answer (score 0):

The first address (or any address, for that matter) may be localhost (127.0.0.1) if the message is transferred between two different software entities on the same computer.

In this case, the first `Received:` header shows that the message is delivered both to and from `samsa.sur5r.net`.

In the absence of other information, I would assume that the (human) sender was logged on to that computer and his MUA (e-mail client) delivered the message to a locally-running MTA.

This is not unusual for Unix-like systems that run a local MTA (e.g. Sendmail or Postfix) - local MUAs will send to the local MTA, which will in turn deliver the message to the next MTA en route to the destination.

If the e-mail is from a mailing list, it could be that the list-server is co-located with its MTA, and is therefore configured to send its messages via localhost.

You may also also see localhost in other cases where a message is transferred between two MTAs on the same server.  Maybe a firewall or spam filter is colocated with an MTA.  Or the last-hop MTA may be colocated with the destination IMAP server.